# Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type in Azure Mobile service DataObject

Tags: c#, mysql, wordpress, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have `Azure Mobile Service` which is fetching data from single(want data fri only this one table ) wordpress `wp_posts` table.

In the model class I have defined the `[Key]` for `Primary Key` .There is only one `PK` for table `wp_posts` but I'm getting error -

> Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type

I need to define correct `composite key` with respect to table `wp_posts` can anyone find out the way?

`wp_posts.cs`

```
[Table("wp_posts")]
public class wp_posts: EntityData
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }    
    public int post_author { get; set; }    
    public DateTime post_date { get; set; }    
    public DateTime post_date_gmt { get; set; }    
    public string post_content { get; set; }    
    public string post_title { get; set; }
    public string post_excerpt { get; set; }
    public string post_status { get; set; }    
    public string comment_status { get; set; }
    public string ping_status { get; set; }    
    public string post_password { get; set; }    
    public string post_name { get; set; }    
    public string to_ping { get; set; }
    public string pinged { get; set; }
    public DateTime post_modified { get; set; }    
    public DateTime post_modified_gmt { get; set; }
    public string post_content_filtered { get; set; }    
    public int post_parent { get; set; }
    public string guid { get; set; }
    public int menu_order { get; set; }
    public string post_type { get; set; }    
    public string post_mime_type { get; set; }    
    public int comment_count { get; set; }
}
```

Table Strucutre wordpress mySQL database.

```
Table: wp_posts
    Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
    ID  bigint(20) unsigned     PRI & IND Pt4       auto_increment
    post_author bigint(20) unsigned     IND 0    
    post_date   datetime        IND Pt3 0000-00-00 00:00:00  
    post_date_gmt   datetime            0000-00-00 00:00:00  
    post_content    longtext                 
    post_title  text                 
    post_excerpt    text                 
    post_status varchar(20)     IND PT2 publish  
    comment_status  varchar(20)         open     
    ping_status varchar(20)         open     
    post_password   varchar(20)              
    post_name   varchar(200)        IND      
    to_ping text                 
    pinged  text                 
    post_modified   datetime            0000-00-00 00:00:00  
    post_modified_gmt   datetime            0000-00-00 00:00:00  
    post_content_filtered   longtext                
    post_parent bigint(20) unsigned     IND 0    
    guid    varchar(255)                 
    menu_order  int(11)         0    
    post_type   varchar(20)     IND Pt1 post     
    post_mime_type  varchar(100)                 
    comment_count   bigint(20)          0    
    Indexes

    Keyname Type    Field
    PRIMARY PRIMARY ID
    post_name   INDEX   post_name
    type_status_date    INDEX   post_type
    post_status
    post_date
    ID
    post_parent INDEX   post_parent
    post_author INDEX   post_author
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Apps has some fairly strict requirements on the table so that it can be used for offline sync.  See chapter 3 of http://aka.ms/zumobook for details.

This table does not meet those requirements.  Specifically, the ID is not a string, there is no updatedAt or version fields.  If you are doing soft delete (which in a mobile app, you need to), then you also need a deleted field.

Take a look at the [EntityData class](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity/EntityData.cs) - you will note that the ID field is already defined and is an alternate definition to yours.

Comment: thank you for detail link and description given :) liked it.